# How to update rows in BigQuery based on value in repeated field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to update the values in a repeated field for certain rows in a BigQuery table. The rows to be updated are selected based on values in the repeated field. I can't figure out how to do accomplish this. For example, let's say I have a schema like this:

```
move_id: integer
color: string
moved_quants: repeated
moved_quants.quantity = integer
moved_quants.value = float
```

And the following data:

[image]

My goal is to update the value of moved_quants.value to 0.6 * the quantity for any row that contains at least one moved_quants.value = 0. Previously, I had to perform this same task based on the color, and that was relatively simple:

```sql
UPDATE
  `testing`
SET
  moved_quants = ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(0.6 * quantity AS value)
    FROM
    UNNEST(moved_quants)
  )
WHERE color = 'red'
```

However, now I need to update the rows that have at least one `moved_quants.value = 0` and I can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have figured it out:

```
UPDATE
  `testing`
SET
  moved_quants = ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(0.6 * quantity AS value)
    FROM
    UNNEST(moved_quants)
  )
WHERE
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(
    (SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(moved_quants) WHERE inventory_value = 0)
  )) > 0
```

Is that right?